# Activity reloads automatically on nexus

Tags: android

First of all, apologies if this question must not be posted here. There is strange thing I need to know. I am using an app with 2 activities. The first one has a button named "Go to 2nd Activity". The second one has a button named "go back". The first activity is my starting activity. Now, when I press "Go to 2nd activity", I start an intent of 2nd activity. When I click "go back" on 2nd activity, I finish the intent of 2nd activity.

So, the problem is the first activity gets reloaded in LG nexus when I use "go back". I tried it on my HTC Desire X  and on sony xperia too but I can see them same as before(no reloading). Can anyone explain this?

Comment: What do you want to happen? The way I understood your post is that the first activity looks the same when you close the second one and does not reload.

Comment: @Razgriz I don't want the activity to load again when I go back (since its only happening in Nexus)

Answer (score 0):

Its only call onResume() When you go back from your second activity.

If you need to reload the activity, Finish the activity while made call to second activity.

And start new intent for mainactivity when click goback event in second activity.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Can you please tell me what to write in onResume of activity so that it won't reload when I come back to it?